# How do I list out @replies using the twitter API using PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

I have a website where users can enter their Twitter Login information. This site will connect with the Twitter API.

I want, when someone their twitter login information, that it lists out @replies with slightly different queries. They are:

- All the @mentions anyone has ever made about the current logged in user, sorted by time/date
- All the @mentions another specific user has ever made to the logged in user, sorted by time/date
- All the @mentions the logged in user has made about another specific user, sorted by time/date

There are some great code examples of how to achieve twitter functionalities here(http://devzone.zend.com/article/4431) but nothing specific that shows how to list out the @replies and how to query them.

How do I list out @replies using the twitter API using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should answer your question: http://pascal.vanhecke.info/2008/02/27/how-not-to-miss-twitter-your_username-replies/